# How to pass multiple parameters from Angular form to make POST request?

Tags: java, angular

```
onSubmit(Values from form here?){
 this.http.post("A URL", legacyURL).subscribe();

 }
```

Comment: Do you want to call 2 URLs at the same time? "A URL" and the legacyURL? You need  2 separate calls for that. One call for "A URL" and another for the legacyURL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your question, if my understanding is correct, You want to pass parameters while making post request.

You can do something like this:

```
const val = this.form.value;

 this.http.post('url', {
      first_name: val.first_name,
      last_name: val.last_name,
      email: val.email,
    })
      .subscribe(response => {

      });
```

Comment: Thanks! this helped

Comment: My pleasure. Could you also upvote the answer?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the HttpParams library to add multiple params in your request headers.

```
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

onSubmit(values val){
  let params = new HttpParams()
      .set('username', val.username)
      .set('password', val.password)

  this.http.post("A URL", params).subscribe();

}
```